# Search a parenthesis in Datatable

Tags: javascript, filter, datatable

I use the `dataTables.columnFilter` add-on for **Datatables (1.10.4)**.

When argument `bRegex` is `true`, I want to search a parenthesis.

Indeed, when I search a parenthesis and the argument `bRegex` is `true`, this character doesn't seem to be taken into account, whereas it's not the case when `bRegex` is `false`.

```
.columnFilter
({
    aoColumns:[{type:"text",bRegex:true} //texte//
})
```

Comment: maybe because `(` is a special keyword in regex? if you want to use it to search this litteral char, you have to escape it: `\(`

Answer (score 0):

#### The metacharacters:

The metacharacters used in Regular Expressions are :

```
! ^ $ ( ) [ ] { } ? + * . / \ |
```

To search for a metacharacters you have to escape it with a : `\`

Exemple:

```
regex    | Search for
-------- | ----------
/What?/  | "Wha" or "What"  
/What\?/ | "What?"
```

Metacharacters don't need to be escaped in a Class, except for:

- `/`, end of Regex.
- `]`, end of class symbol.
- `\`, if you search for an `\`

If you want to search for a `-` in a class, it can be placed at the end or the beginning of it:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions.
I discovered, in the jquery.dataTables.js file, the following condition :

```
    search = regex ?
        search :
        _fnEscapeRegex( search );
```

with the _fnEscapeRegex function - in the same file - which escape especially the parenthesis characters.
So, to escape parenthesis when bRegex is equal to true, i've just added the following code, just before the code above :

```
 var _escape_parenthesis = new RegExp( '(\\' + [ '(', ')'].join('|\\') + ')', 'g' );        
search = regex ? search.replace( _escape_parenthesis, '\\$1' ):search;
```

Thank you to Kaddath and Pierre Lebon for their explanations about the meaning of escape in Regular Expressions.